# Group items cannot be used except in INTO or VALUES clause

Tags: sql, oracle, cobol

This sql seems okay but hit error during compiling ..

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
INTO :W9-TOT-TRXN
FROM IRC02
WHERE SUBSTR(P9_IRC_PST_DT,1,6) = :Ws-DATE-YM
AND F9_IRC_FI = :W9-FI-PARAM
AND P9_IRC_PRIN_CRN = :F9-IR025-CRN
AND F9_IRC_LOC_ACCT = :F9-IR025-LOC-ACCT
```

The error message as below :

Error at line 757, column 60 in file RCCO.cbl

```
                    WHERE SUBSTR(P9_IRC_PST_DT,1,6) = :Ws-DATE-YM
```

PCB-S-00204, Group items cannot be used except in INTO or VALUES clause

```
01 Ws-DATE-YMD.
03 Ws-DATE-YM.
   05 W9-DATE-YY      PIC 9(04) VALUE ZEROES.
   05 W9-DATE-MM      PIC 9(02) VALUE ZEROES.
03 W9-DATE-DD         PIC 9(02) VALUE ZEROES.
```

any idea ? thanks :)

Comment: WOW!! COBOL!! +1 just because its nostalgic :-)

Comment: Is `Ws-DATE-YM` a [group item](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10826/pco04dat.htm#sthref494)? I'd hazard a guess it's a group of separate year and month items, in which case it looks like you'd need to reference the elementary items separately in two clauses.

Comment: I have declared separately... refer to above update.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Group items cannot be used as host variables in the `where` clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10826/pco04dat.htm#sthref494) as the error says. You'll need to reference the elementary items separately, something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
INTO :W9-TOT-TRXN
FROM IRC02
WHERE SUBSTR(P9_IRC_PST_DT,1,4) = :Ws-DATE-YM.W9-DATE-YY
AND SUBSTR(P9_IRC_PST_DT,5,2) = :Ws-DATE-YM.W9-DATE-MM
AND F9_IRC_FI = :W9-FI-PARAM
AND P9_IRC_PRIN_CRN = :F9-IR025-CRN
AND F9_IRC_LOC_ACCT = :F9-IR025-LOC-ACCT
```

Or maybe more performant:

```
WHERE SUBSTR(P9_IRC_PST_DT,1,6) = :Ws-DATE-YM.W9-DATE-YY || :Ws-DATE-YM.W9-DATE-MM
```

Though I'm going from the docs rather than from experience, so this is completely untested; also not sure if you'd need to include the parent `Ws-DATE-YMD` before both parts, or of it will be happy with one level.

Comment: I declared a new variable as string to move Ws-DATE-YM to Wx-DT-YM . Then it solved my error. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use REDEFINES to avoid adding the MOVE statement :

```
03 Ws-DATE-YM.
   05 W9-DATE-YY      PIC 9(04) VALUE ZEROES.
   05 W9-DATE-MM      PIC 9(02) VALUE ZEROES.
03 Wx-DT-YM PIC 9(6) REDEFINES Ws-DATE-YM.
```